# How Do I Keep A JFrame Above All Other Applications (That have open or will open) Such As Powerpoint

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe

I am creating a news ticker (that narrow, black box at the bottom of the screen that stretches the length of the screen with text of other news that scrolls by). My application opens other programs. In this case, the powerpoint presentation it opens, opens over my jframe. I need my jframe to always be visible
Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: Another name for what you describe is a "scrolling marquee."

Comment: AFAIK setAlwaysOnTop works for JDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Window#setAlwaysOnTop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29):

> Sets whether this window should always be above other windows.

```
myJFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Comment: Wow, that was a lot simpler than I thought. Thanks! I have a quick question. Just an extra thing I suppose. My problem is otherwise solved. How exactly is java doing this? Under the hood that is. Does the OS control the z-index of all windows? Is java somehow using the win32 api?

Comment: Yes, underneath Swing fires an `alwaysOnTop` property change. this ultimately goes back to the OS. Hasnt changed since the days of `AWT`.

Answer (score 1):

[myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29);